# How to find specific item with Linq based on multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

I have pretty simple query:

```
//user from UserManager from default AccountController from .net Identity
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

var product = await Task.Run(() 
    => db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id && u.ProductId == id));
```

What i want to do is to find specific `product` in `WatchedProducts` list. Model of it looks like this:

```
public class WatchedProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` have list of `WatchedProducts`.

My question is, why istead of getting `WatchedProduct product` i get an `IQueryable<WatchedProduct> product`?

Comment: linq returns an IQueryable so you can continue to append additional linq calls to the end. This is ideal. If you want an enumerable or something else, you can do AsEnumerable()

Comment: You'll not get a list or an object until you call `ToList`, `First` or similar methods. Until called the object is still a "query".

Comment: There is no point in using `await Task.Run()`.

Comment: Im not best in ASP MVC, but im using that query in HTTP requests (webapi) so i added that Task Run. I dont know why someone downvote my question without explenation

Comment: @michasaucer The reason which I shared `FirstOrDefaultAsync` is because you should never use `Task.Run()` when you have an async method like `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you are using method `Where()`. `Where()` method filters your data based on your lambda-expression `=> u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id && u.ProductId == id` and returns `IQueryable<TSource>` or `IEnumerable<TSource>`(See great explanation in answer by Reza Aghaei).

If you want to get WaterProduct product then just get it through `FirstOrDefault()` method:

```
var product = await Task.Run(() 
    => db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id && u.ProductId == id)
       .FirstOrDefault());
```

You did not get any data as you did not materialized your query. It is called deferred execution. Deferred execution means that your linq code will not be executed in database until you need necessary data. So to materialize data or execute your query in database you should call methods like:

```
foreach, toList(), First(), FirstOrDefault(), Single(), SingleOrDefault(), etc...
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't think you need to run your linq statements in an async fashion - so you can skip the "await Task.Run", like this: 

`var product = db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id && u.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: And it doesn't have anything to do with deferred execution. It's because `Where` returns `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Why not ``FirstOrDefault`` instead of ``Where``?

Answer (score 2):

It's because `Where` extension method returns `IEnumerable<TSource>`. In case of db set, it returns `IQueryable<TSource>` which is `IEnumerable<TSource>`.

In your case, since you are using async/await pattern, you can use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to get a single item as a result:

```
var p = await db.WatchedProducts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id &&
                                                          u.ProductId == id)
```

Comment: @StepUp Right, in fact it depend to the type which is extended by extension method. In case of `DbSet<T>` it returns `IQueryable<T>` which is `IEnumerable<T>` in fact. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use SingleOrDefault

From what i can tell your result should be unique since you are using product id which would be unique

```
var product = await Task.Run(() 
    => db.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id && u.ProductId == id));
```

This will return one item or null if none was found. Caution it will throw an exception if more then one item is found, which it shouldn't since product id would most likely be unique and if it finds more the one you would know that you messed up in your database that you have multiple products with the same id

If its acceptable that that query can have more then one record as a result then use 
`FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` but then the logic wouldn't be quite correct since it doesn't make sense to have a query that needs to return one or none, to return the first on the list.